# Why isn't short variable declaration allowed at package level in Go?

Tags: go

This is allowed:

```
package main

var a = 3

...
```

But this isn't:

```
package main

a := 3

...
```

Why not? Why couldn't short variable declaration outside a function be treated regular declaration without a type? Just to simplify parsing?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to Ian Lance Taylor in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/qTZemuGDV6o/IyCwXPJsUFIJ) shortly after the public announcement:

> At the top level, every declaration begins with a keyword. This simplifies parsing.

Comment: Is there any explanation anywhere as to how does this help parsing ?

Comment: Still, no explanation on why and how exactly it simplifies parsing...

Answer (score 8):

To quote from [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec):

> Short variable declarations may appear only inside functions. In some
>   contexts such as the initializers for "if", "for", or "switch"
>   statements, they can be used to declare local temporary variables.

You can think of `var` statement like `const`, `type`, and `func`, in the package level you have to specify what's kind of statement you are declaring.

Well , it's not a real shorthand ,  `a, b := 12` can't compile, `var a,b = 12` do.

Answer (score 3):

Outside a function, every statement must begin with a keyword (var, func, and so on), and so the `:=` construct is not available.

See [here](http://tour.golang.org/basics/10). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Matt, just curious, what was the reason that you edited my answer? could you please share your feedback so that I can improve my answers in future. thank you.