# Declaring variables in Go

Tags: go, variable-declaration

The Go documentation indicates one should use the shorthand:

```
x := "Hello World"
```

as opposed to the long form

```
var x string = "Hello World"
```

to improve readability. While the following works:

```
package main   
import "fmt"
var x string = "Hello World"
func main() {
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

This does not:

```
package main
import "fmt"
x := "Hello World"
func main() {
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

and gives the error "non-declaration statement outside function body".  If instead I declare it within the function:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
   x := "Hello World"
   fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Then it works just fine.  It seems I can only use the shorthand within the function that uses the variable.  Is this the case?  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: +Charlie Thanks for the link to the specs.  If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't short variable declaration allowed at package level in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854033/why-isnt-short-variable-declaration-allowed-at-package-level-in-go)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specification states that [short variable declarations can only be used in functions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

With this restriction, everything at package level begins with a keyword. This [simpflies parsing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/qTZemuGDV6o/IyCwXPJsUFIJ).