# What is difference between "var deckSize = 20" and "deckSize := 20" in GoLang, if written outside the main function body?

Tags: go

I am new to Go, and learning the basics of the language. This is where I am stuck.

I understand from the basic course that `var x int = 10` and `x := 10` are supposed to be equivalent, the latter being a shorthand notation. 
It all made sense till these two were inside the main() function.

That means:

```
package main
import "fmt"   

func main() {
    var x int = 20
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

,

```
func main() {
    var x := 20
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

and

```
func main() {
    x := 20
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

All these run fine.
But when I move this variable outside the main function, the behavior is different and I couldn't find an explanation in the tutorials I could find.

That means,

```
package main

import "fmt"

var x int = 20

func main() {
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

and

```
var x = 20

func main() {
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

run as expected, but,

```
x := 20

func main() {
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Gives an error :

> syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body

Why did this statement become a "non-declaration" one, and how is it different from same syntax being used inside the main() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designers of Go chose not to allow this shorthand outside of functions. The Go folks hint at their reasons [here](https://tour.golang.org/basics/10)

> Inside a function, the := short assignment statement can be used in place of a var declaration with implicit type.
>
> Outside a function, every statement begins with a keyword (var, func, and so on) and so the := construct is not available.

The designers preferred every single statement at the top level to start with a keyword. Perhaps for aesthetics. Perhaps for ease of parsing. Perhaps because the top level things are the things you can export if you capitalize.

This construct is called both a *short assignment statement* (in the Go Tour) but [officially, in the grammar](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) it is indeed called a short variable declaration! Given that it officially *is* a declaration, the error message, as you are alluding to, is IMHO wrong! They could do better. They should say "short declaration found outside function."

*UPDATE*

This question looks like a dupe: [Why isn't short variable declaration allowed at package level in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854033/why-isnt-short-variable-declaration-allowed-at-package-level-in-go)

However, if the question is not "why is it not allowed?" but rather "why does the error message say it is a non-declaration?" then it's a good, distinct question.

Comment: Hey @Ray, didn't have enough credits to upvote your answer back then. Just found it today, paid my debts. Thank again for the help.